# Why do I get warning C28182 when using boost polymorphic_cast?

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2013, code-analysis

I get this error ([C12182](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh329451.aspx)) compiling the Release|x86 build of my code when using `boost::polymorphic_cast` to ensure that a pointer is not null.

```
Warning 2   warning C28182: Dereferencing NULL pointer. 'tv' contains the same NULL value as '(dva::TimedValue *)=(tv)' did. : Lines: 808, 810, 812, 813, 808, 810, 812 c:\path\to\my\code\timedvalue.cpp   812 1   mylibrary
```

**My question is, *why* do I get this warning?** What should I do about it? The `polymorphic_cast` will throw if the pointer is null. So far as I understand, this code is correct. What am I missing?

Here's my code. `apr_time_t` is a 64-bit int, and m_cobjs is a vector of pointers to a class from which `TimedValue` is derived. The commented-out `ASSERT_PTR` throws an exception if the pointer is null, and resolves the warning if I un-comment it.

```
void TimedValueTable::RemovePointsBefore(apr_time_t time)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m_cobjs.size(); )
    {
        TimedValue *tv = boost::polymorphic_cast<TimedValue *>(m_cobjs[i]);
        // ASSERT_PTR(tv);
        if (tv->get_Time() < time)
            delete tv;
        else
            ++i;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm more worried about you deleting the pointers you store in the container, but you don't remove them. In fact, as you don't increase the counter variable `i` when you delete, you ***will*** have undefined behavior in the next iteration, as then you get the same `TimedValue` pointer again, but now you dereference a deleted pointer.

Comment: Thanks @JoachimPileborg actually the destructor of TimedValue takes care of that. It's a very untidy implementation but it is done.